# Average 3 Months in Power BI per Line of Month

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to show the month sales x the average sales from the last 3/6 months, however when I put the month information in the rows, the line apears a sum, the average only apears in the totals.

There is a away to show the average in the lines as weel?

Thank you!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BIup.png)

Use the formula for average and datesinperiod

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to do this, using the function "ALL" after the calculation of the average, and using "date" to find the actual month as base for the average:

```
Avg3M = calculate(
                    average(Sheet1[Valor]), DATESINPERIOD(Sheet1[Mês],DATE(year(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())-1,DAY(TODAY())),-3,MONTH)
                    ,ALL(Sheet1)
                    )
```